# How to access upper left cell of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my Python's Pandas dataframe. How can I access the upper left cell where `"gender"` is in and change the text? `"gender"` is not in `names.columns`. So I thought this might be `names.index.name` but that was not it.

```
import pandas as pd

names = pd.DataFrame({'births': {0: 7065, 1: 2604, 2: 2003, 3: 1939, 4: 1746},
 'gender': {0: 'F', 1: 'M', 2: 'F', 3: 'M', 4: 'F'},
 'name': {0: 'mary', 1: 'anna', 2: 'emma', 3: 'elizabeth', 4: 'minnie'},
 'year': {0: 1880, 1: 1880, 2: 1880, 3: 1880, 4: 1880}})

names = names.pivot_table(index=['name', 'year'], columns='gender', values='births').reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Please post complete, runnable code that generates `names` (or another df with the same behavior).

Comment: post the output from `df.info()`, it's probably a column so you can check this to by looking at `df.columns`

Comment: @MikeGraham yes just posted my code. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: @EdChum tried your suggestions but did not see "gender"

Comment: @MaxU `"gender"` is not in `names.columns` so `names.rename()` does not work..

Comment: so it must be in `data.index` also this `data.index.name` is the `name` attribute so this is why it's `None`

Comment: @EdChum yes that's what I thought too but `names.index.name` is `None`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`gender` is the name of the columns index:

```
In [16]:
names.columns.name = 'something'
names

Out[16]:
something       name  year     F     M
0               anna  1880   NaN  2604
1          elizabeth  1880   NaN  1939
2               emma  1880  2003   NaN
3               mary  1880  7065   NaN
4             minnie  1880  1746   NaN
```

You can see this when you look at the `.columns` object:

```
In [18]:
names.columns

Out[18]:
Index(['name', 'year', 'F', 'M'], dtype='object', name='gender')
```

I guess it does confusingly look like the index from the output

Comment: Oh that is it! Thank you!